# AWS CLI Output to CSV to include Column Headers

Tags: csv, amazon-ec2, header, output

I am very new to AWS CLI and I am looking to get a basic output (to CSV) of some of a customers resources.

I can get the data I need, mostly, but the output does not include column headers so it is difficult to pass the data on to colleagues to deal with.

As an example I am using this command:-

aws elb describe-load-balancers --output text --query 'LoadBalancerDescriptions[*].[LoadBalancerName,DNSName,VPCId]' > c:\aws\ELB.csv

the output is this:-

[image]

However, I would prefer it to be this:-

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You could try the `table` output option as shown below

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --output table \
        --query 'LoadBalancerDescriptions[*].[LoadBalancerName,DNSName,VPCId]' > c:\aws\ELB.csv
```

It gives you formatted output, you can then use grep or other bash tools to exclude lines you do not want.

Comment: The issue is: How can I trust the column names in a different output format? Example, when using JSON output in describing snapshots we have a "State".  For text this is "status" for some reason? So this is a good answer, but some of us want the names for filtering.